# Find Dynamic columns of a RadGrid

Tags: asp.net

```
I created Dynamic columns (textBox) in RadGrid on a Click Event. How do I find those Controls on another Click Event.



  for (int i = 0; i < objISTUserDetailsObjectList.Count; i++)
            {
                tempCol = new GridTemplateColumn();
                tempCol.ItemTemplate = new DynamicTemplateCoulmn("txtQuantity" + i, "numericTextBox");        
                tempCol.UniqueName = "Users" + i;
                tempCol.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                tempCol.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                tempCol.FooterStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                gvwISTProduct.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(tempCol);

        }
```

I an unable to find the "txtxQuantity" on another Click event although i find it in Grids ItemDataBound event.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your requirement? Then also please check below link and let me know if any concern.
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/get-checkbox-control-added-dynamically-in-gridtemplate-column.aspx